# Does LaTeX have some incrementation system to use with description lists?

Tags: numbering

Sometimes I'm writing exercises on LaTeX. Suppose I do the following list:

- Exercise 1.
- Exercise 2.
- Exercise 3.

But then I find that the first exercise is not relevant anymore and want to erase it. With what I know about LaTeX until now, I'd have to rewrite 1 in the place of 2 and 2 in the place of 3. Does LaTeX has some kind of increment/variable system to help me with this?

I know about the existence of [`enumerate`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures#Enumerate). But I'm using [`description`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures#Description) which does not automatically numerates the items. Is it possible to write something inside the `[First]` that allows me to have automatic numeration just as `enumerate`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no difficulty to define an enumeration to look like your example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\textbullet\ Exercise\ \arabic*.}]

\item An item
\item Another one
\item And another one
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

If you want all your first level enumerations to look like this, you can set the label globally like this: (the `1` defines the first level).

```
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\textbullet\ Exercise\ \arabic*.}}
```

Then you don't have to add the code after each `\begin{enumerate}`.

Comment: Thanks. There is another thing I'm curious about. Can I define a variable in a way that whenever referenced, this variable will increase by 1?

For example, if my document has:
x
x
x

It would yield in the rendered version.
1
2
3

Comment: @Voyska Sure. This is what LaTeX counters are for.  Perhaps this question will help? [LaTeX - Numbering](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52735)